# Show progress on long-running process

Tags: c#, asynchronous, asp.net-core

I have a few server-side processes that can take very long times to run (30-60m). These are a result of calling a web API from my webserver, and throttling the requests to match the maximum request rate of the service.

I want to be able to display the progress of this on the client, how can I go about doing this? Where do I start?

Previous answers have hinted at SignalR, but that does not seem to be a thing with Asp.Net Core.

**Edit:** It looks like SignalR is a thing with Asp.Net core. As this is the case, I have a followup question:

I'm using AngularJS and managing the client-side state via AJAX requests to API endpoints. Are there any potential coding or performance "gotchas" when trying to also utilize SignalR in conjunction?

**Additionally, are there alternatives that don't add SignalR as a dependency?** It looks like it requires a beta-version of .Net Core, I'd rather stay in stable-release-land if at all possible.

Comment: SignalR exists with ASP.NET Core : https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR

Comment: Another option is to create a running process structure. For example, you can have in your data base a table with two columns: process_code and done. When you start you process, you return a process_code to your client. Then, your client monitor the process through another service using the process_code. When the process finishes, just set the done column to true. With this, your client would be able to know when the process is finished.

Comment: Yea, SinglarR is there and it should work more or less (its still in beta state and not done). But you'd need a mix of Background processes (neither ASP.NET nor ASP.NET Core are suitable for long running processes as their lifetime may depend on external factors like IIS Server stopping the process), with SinglarR and ASP.NET + Client-side (JavaScript). The question is to broad, hence I most vote for closing it. You should reduce it to one concrete, solvable problem you are having with it, not broad architectural questions

Comment: @Tseng I am not ensure sure what is available in the first place, so it's pretty difficult to pin it down to `one concrete, solvable problem`. Once I understand the gist of what ASP.NET can provide in this space, then I can start to narrow the problem down. If The suggested is to save some sort of state on the server side, and just make AJAX calls to retrieve it, my question would then be how do I manage the server-side state and reliably pass that to the same client.

Comment: There is Google and professional resources (blogs, books, etc) which provide this kind of broad architectural questions. These broad questions aren't suitable for StackOverflow, as there is "no definite answer" to it and can be solved in many ways. http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic  _but if your question generally covers a specific programming problem, or a software algorithm, or software tools commonly used by programmers; and is a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development then you’re in the right place to ask your question!_ And your question is neither of

Comment: Are more suitable place would be http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com, which covers general software engineering practices including software architecture

Comment: @Tseng I believe your interpretation of the question is off from it's actual meaning. It's not nearly as broad as you seem to be interpreting it as, there are many other accepted questions of a similar nature on SO. Also please take into consideration that since stackoverflow tries to be at the top of google search results, almost all queries return back here to questions and answers about older technologies.

My question most definitely meets the above criteria, this is not even remotely related to `general software engineering practices` and is related to a very specific technology.

Comment: @Tseng when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: @gnat: I wasn't implying that he should post it on multiple SE pages, but close/delete this and only ask on the other page, as this type of question isn't very suitable for SO.

Answer (score -1):

You can use SignalR and the [IProgress](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138298(v=vs.110).aspx) interface to handle this. The basic implementation is something like this:

*Server-side*

```
[HubName("messageHub")]
public class MessageHub : Hub  // This is your server-side SignalR
{
    public async Task Countdown(IProgress<int> progress) // This is your IProgress
    {            
         // 60 second countdown for an example
         // NOT TESTED
         for (int i = 1; i <= 61; i += 1)
         {             
              await Task.Delay(1000);
              progress.Report(i);                    
         }
     }
}
```

Client-side

```
// Hub connection
//
var messageConnection = $.hubConnection(url);
var messageHub = messageConnection.createHubProxy('MessageHub');
$.connection.hub.logging = true
```

Comment: I'm currently using AngularJS and handle the client-state via AJAX requests to API endpoints. Do you know if there are potential "gotchas" when using signalR as well?

Comment: SignalR is a broad topic an takes a bit of fiddling to get up an running, but works great in scenarios like you've described.