# How to maintain and return progress of a task?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, asp.net-core

This is (hopefully) a less broad version of this: [Show progress on long-running process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41583797/show-progress-on-long-running-process)

I have a long running task in ASP.Net Core, and want to be able to provide progress for that task without using SignalR.

**Here is an example endpoint:**

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("/getter/world/{world}/cities")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetCities(int world)
{
    ApiGetter getter = new ApiGetter(_config);
    try
    {
        //3rd party cookie
        if (!await IsValidCookie(getter, world))
        {
            return BadRequest("Invalid Session");
        }

        IEnumerable<PlayerRank> rankings = await getter.GetWorldScoreRankings(world);
        List<City> cities = new List<City>();
        foreach (PlayerRank rank in rankings)
        {
            try
            {
                IEnumerable<City> playerCities = await getter.GetPlayerCities(rank, 5);
                IEnumerable<City> uniqueCities = playerCities.GroupBy(c => c.CityID).Select(c => c.First()).ToList();
                cities.AddRange(uniqueCities);

                _repository.InsertCities(uniqueCities);
            }
            catch (DbUpdateException ex) when ((ex.InnerException as MySqlException)?.Number == 1062)
            {
                continue;
            }
        }
        return Ok(cities.Count);
    }
    catch (DbUpdateException ex) when ((ex.InnerException as MySqlException)?.Number == 1062)
    {
        return BadRequest("City data already inserted for today");
    }
}
```

This endpoint is managing multiple things, I am aware of the issues with not following SRP.

To try and avoid the "Question too broad" flag, here is what I want to sort out:

**What I need to know:**

- How to keep a record of the progress of the `foreach` loop
- How to return that to the client upon request

**What I don't need to know:**

- How to make an AJAX request
- How to poll with JavaScript
- How to make endpoints

Since I can't return multiple time from the `GetCities()` method, I assume I'll need an additional endpoint that I can call to retrieve the current progress. If so, how do I keep record of that progress in a way that it is available to that other endpoint?

Optional if simple/in-scope: how do I ensure only the user that started the task sees the progress?

**Edit:** Would the Session TempData be appropriate for this? Write the progress to TempData, and further requests read it?

Answer (score 1):

Your question already covers the basic "how do I get the status of a long running task" so I'll assume that you did your homework about the easy solutions.

One way to make sure that only the client that initiated the request can check the progress, is to pass a client secret to the request (a client generated string or number). That way, only by knowing that secret you can check the progress. *The downside of this approach if that if the client dies, it might loose that secret.*

With that "client secret" in mind, let's answer the questions:

> How to keep a record of the progress of the foreach loop

Use the client secret to keep track create a map of progress. Use a map of some sort (in memory or redis) to map `client secret <-> progress`. On each for loop iteration, update the map and invalidate the entry after a certain time.

> How to return that to the client upon request

Have an endpoint that checks the progress using the client secret.

> how do I ensure only the user that started the task sees the progress?

The client secret solves that.